# Expectation of $\mathbb{E}(Tr(X^T A X))$ and $Var(Tr(X^T A X))$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, random-variable, expected-value, linear-algebra

What is the expectation: $\mathbb{E}(Tr(X^T A X))$ and $Var(Tr(X^T A X))$

when $X_{i,j} \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ where $n>k$  and $A$ is a given p.s.d matrix (not random)?

Answer (score 2):

Since trace is linear,
$$[\text{Tr}(X^TAX)]=[\text{Tr}(AXX^T)]=\text{Tr}([AXX^T])=\text{Tr}(A[XX^T])$$
should help you towards the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Are there any expectation results for gram matrices formed through random matrix $X$? Would like to know of the variance term as well and onwards towards the solution.